PySpark StreamingQueryException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with Elasticsearch Spark Connector
I'm working on a PySpark streaming job where I need to write streaming data from Kafka to Elasticsearch. I am using:
Spark Version: 3.5.2
Elasticsearch Spark Connector: org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.13:8.10.2 Scala Version: 2.13
The goal is to process and correlate streaming data in PySpark and write the final output to an Elasticsearch index. However, I'm running into the following error during execution:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harshvardhanmatta/iceberg_pyspark_kafka_project/correlation/correlation_hotspot_mikrotik_5.py", line 182, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/harshvardhanmatta/iceberg_pyspark_kafka_project/correlation/correlation_hotspot_mikrotik_5.py", line 174, in main
    es_write_query.processAllAvailable()
  ...
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 2fb60ac0-7734-404a-b02a-e5812e8b91f5, runId = 3800f064-6b8b-4d7d-b6ad-60f500eddbb2] terminated with exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 20 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 20.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 432) (10.5.49.178 executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)'
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.<init>(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.$anonfun$addBatch$5(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:72)

I am writing the final streaming DataFrame to Elasticsearch using the following configuration:
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .option("es.resource", "correlated-data") \
    .option("es.nodes", "137.59.52.242") \
    .option("es.port", "9200") \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "elastic") \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "xxxx") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint") \
    .start()

Error Analysis:
The error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError usually indicates a version mismatch or an incompatibility between the Spark version and the connector. I suspect the issue could be:
A mismatch between Spark 3.5.2, the Elasticsearch Spark connector, or Scala version.
Potentially incompatible methods in the Spark SQL streaming API and the Elasticsearch connector.
Actions Taken So Far:

Verified that the Spark and Scala versions are consistent: using Scala 2.13.
Updated the connector to org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.13:8.10.2.
Added appropriate configurations to the Spark session and connector.

Question:

Has anyone faced a similar issue with Spark 3.5.x and the Elasticsearch connector?
Should I be using a different connector version for Spark 3.5.2?
Are there any known compatibility issues or fixes for this specific error?

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

According to a github issue from elastic search, spark 3.5 is not yet supported. I would try your workflow with an older spark version, like 3.4.x:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/2210

According to a github issue from elasticsearch, spark 3.5 is not yet supported.
I would try your workflow with an older spark version, like 3.4.3, which was mentioned to be supported in the same github issue thread.
